# Date content comparison if it is greater then todays date

Tags: string, powershell

I am looking for some script in PowerShell that will compare the date present in an inside text file as content and compare if that date is >today`+15 days then print the file name.

Also, if that script can compare the date as mentioned above along with the other string if both conditions are matching then print the file name.

The below command gives me the output for those which have matching string same as hello and was created 30 days back. But now I want to fulfill the above two conditions no matter when the file was created.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\vpaul\Downloads\functional-script\*.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'Hello', 'Hell' | Where CreationTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)| Export-Csv C:\Users\vpaul\Downloads\functional-script\File_Name.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

The output from `Select-String` doesn't have a `CreationTime` property, which is why your filtering fails - `CreationTime` doesn't resolve to anything so it's *always* "less than" any value you provide.

Either do the filtering on `CreationTime` *before* piping to `Select-String`:

```
Get-ChildItem ... |Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6) |Select-String 'Hell' | ...
```

Or use the `Path` property on the output from `Select-String` to look up the files attributes again:

```
Get-ChildItem ... |Select-String 'Hell' |Where-Object {(Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath $_.Path -Name CreationTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} |...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're trying to get and compare a date from a matched text string inside the file, as well as CreationTime file attribute... +15 Days and -6 Days respectively...

Example Text file Content:

```
Hello 4/1/2021
```

You could try something similar to this:

```
$ALL_RECURSED_TXTs = Get-ChildItem -Path '[Folder to Recurse]\*.txt' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6) };

foreach($File in $ALL_RECURSED_TXTs) {
    Get-Content -Path $File.FullName | Select-String -Pattern 'Hello', 'Hell' |
        ForEach-Object { 
            # Find a RegEx match for your Date String that is in the File
            $_ -match 'Hello\s(\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}).*' | Out-Null; 
            if((Get-date($matches[1])) -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(15))) { 
                "$($File.FullName)" | Out-File -FilePath '[Path to Output]\MyPrintedFileNames.txt' -Append;
            } 
        }
}
```

If you want to see your matched lines in your outfile...

```
"$_ : $($File.FullName)" | Out-File -FilePath '[Path to Output]\MyPrintedFileNames.txt' -Append;
```

"but now I want to fulfill the above two conditions no matter when the file was created."

Scrap the Where-Object filter on Get-ChildItem if you want all txt files.

Edit: Getting confused again. Lol. If your txt file date string is not on same line as your "Hello|Hell" it'll get more complex. Good Luck!

Comment: is it possible to apply two conditions if both sting matching from the text file and search those two text file (hello and in other line 22022022 as date) only then show the file path which have above two.??